# What are the consequences of the violation of Gauss-Markov assumptions?

Tags: assumptions, gauss-markov-theorem

If these are the assumptions:

A(1) E(ϵi)=0 for all i
A(2) ϵi and xi´ are independent for all i,i´
A(3) var(ϵi)=σ² < ∞ for all i
A(4) cov(ϵi,ϵi´)=0 for all i ≠ i´

What does the violation of these assumptions do exactly with the parameters of the model and with the p-value?

With a violation of A(3) and A(4) the parameters are not biased, but the p-values are incorrect. But what are the consequences of a violation of A(3) and A(4) with regard to the parameters and the p-values?

I am thankful for any help!

Comment: Please type your question in MathJax.

Answer (score -2):

The Gauss-Markov theorem concludes, under those assumptions, that the MLE for the regression coefficients are determined by least-squares. Therefore, in the model, (say $i\leq 1\leq n$),
$$ y_i = \sum_{j=1}^m a_{i,j}x_j + b_i + \varepsilon_i $$
where $(\varepsilon_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ are IID normal, we can explicitly compute the MLE and find that the coefficients are determined by solving a least-squares linear system. Therefore, we can use the MLE to estimate the uncertainity (hence p-values) from the estimates of the coefficients.

However, let us instead suppose that $(\varepsilon_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ are IID from *double-sided* $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ distribution (so imagine the exponential distribution, but it goes also into the negative direction, there is probably a name to this distribution). Then we have that,
$$ \left|y_i - \sum_{j=1}^m a_{i,j}x_j - b_i \right| \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$$
In this case the MLE will involve *minimizing the sum of absolute-residuals* instead of squared-residuals (because the PDF for the Normal is of the form $\exp(-x^2)$ (ignoring the constants), and the PDF for the Exponential  is of the form $\exp(-x)$ (ignoring the constants)).

Therefore, you have replaced your original problem, which was a least squared problem, into a linear programming problem which has *no closed-form explicit formula* to it. With least squares there is an explicit closed-form solution you can use to estimate parameters. There is an however algorithm for finding it but no explicit immediate formula. Therefore, in a problem like this, you would need to estimate the variation of the estimates using the simplex algorithm. (Alternatively, you can also run Bayesian regression for something like this.)

Comment: Gauss-Markov doesn't have anything to do with maximum likelihood; instead, it states that the OLS estimator (under the assumptions) is the best linear unbiased estimator - and that's all.

Comment: @jbowman Suppose you have a line $y=ax+b$ and data points $(x_i,y_i)$. The assumption is that $y_i - ax_i - b$ is normally distributed. If the variance is $\sigma^2$ then the log-likelihood of the data is equal $L(\sigma) = c - \sum_i (y_i - ax_i - b)/(2\sigma^2)$. If we want to maximize $L(\sigma)$ by choosing $a,b$ then we are solving a least-squares problem.

Comment: Gauss-Markov has nothing to do with distributional assumptions other than the existence of the first two moments of the residuals and homoskedasticity.   You are describing maximum likelihood estimation in the case of Normally-distributed residuals, which *happens* to coincide with the least squares solution - but the question refers to Gauss-Markov, not MLE, so you are coming at it from the wrong direction, so to speak!   See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem.

Comment: Just some comments (no downvote): (1) You describe a [*Laplace distribution.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) (2) When $m=1$ the Simplex algorithm is not essential. A simple geometric algorithm was [discovered in 1757.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2241376) (3) It's important in your comment not to omit the term involving $\log(\sigma)$ in the log likelihood. (4) The question specifically asks how the parameter estimates and p-value change when variances are infinite or errors are correlated.  Your remarks do not appear to address either of those circumstances.